# Angular Cli and AOT issues

Tags: css, angular, angular-aot

I use Angular CLI 1.4.1 in my project and want to build using AOT compilation. However I faced two issues:

1) I have Shop module with Registration component. In the registration.component.css I added line

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

This file exists in the node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/ folder.
However when I run AOT build I get error message:

```
Error: Compilation failed. Resource file not found: C:/library/src/app/shop/book-registration/~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css
    at ModuleResolutionHostAdapter.readResource (C:\library\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\compiler_host.js:387:19)
```

2) I have global file styles.css and it's included in the .angular-cli.json:

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.css"
  ]
```

When I run development build the styles from this file are available on the page. However after AOT build the styles are not loaded.

Please, advise.

Comment: I've got the same issue

Comment: Try to remove the import from .css file and add this line to `styles` in .angular-cli.json file: `"../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"`.

Answer (score 0):

remove import from your component

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

and add reference on this theme into angular-cli.json:

```
"styles" : [
  "styles.css",
  "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"]
```

and try run ng serve again

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. But my question was about AOT compilation where ng serve is not used.